# How to render .vue file in javascript when using ES5? (Trying to use webpack and vue-loader)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I have been trying to migrate a vue project and I unfortunately cannot use import/export in where I am building the application. Therefore, to simplify my problem, I created a project from scratch to build a vue component without the vue-cli.

I have been successful to bring up the vue app with webpack before I created .vue files but after that point I started to get the following error and my .vue file wouldn't render.

```
 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

The code is the following and I'll try to keep it as simple as possible:

index.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var App = require('./App.vue').default;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ... (meta stuff)
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

and lastly the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
          'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        }
    },
    watch: true,
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
};
```

I run `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js` from npm to get the webpack server running. I also did `webpack --config ./webpack.config.js` but then I have to run the index.html in chrome and I thought running a server might actually be better for the bundle.

I am aware that a lot of people had similar problems but for some reason none of the solutions I found out there worked for me. I'd really appreciate some help about which direction I should take to fix this situation.

This article might be helpful but I am not sure how to fix my project with it:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

**Edit On Request**

dev-Dependencies and dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "vueTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use babel ? I do not see it

Comment: I am not using babel for this project because I'm using just ES5

Comment: Could you provide your devDependencies and dependencies in package.json and npm version?? I run your code on my conditions and everything works well.

Comment: I've added them @Guest

Comment: ES5 doesn't support arrow functions, so you'll need to define the render method using a normal function definition: `render: function(h) { return h(App); }`

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem even after changing to ES5 function type

Comment: Are you sure you should be referencing `require('./App.vue').default` and not just `require('./App.vue')`? And are you sure the file path is correct?

Comment: Try to replace this <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script> with this <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>

Comment: Okay actually now that I looked at it, the error disappeared after i changed the function to ES5 style. However, my template still does not show. I'll try few things that you guys have mentioned. Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: Okay I got it working, it eventually led to be a problem about changing the function to ES5 style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has worked thanks to thanksd's comment:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function(h) { return h(App); }
})
```

However, it is important to have `var App = require('./App.vue').default;` especially the default part for the vue files. Hopefully that helps other people as well. I understand that my problem was in the end a simple syntax problem.